Dependent dropdowns in Dynamic Rows
I have a fieldset that I have a dynamic rows component in, where I want to have two dropdowns in each row. The first has a static list of options, and the second I want to populate based on the selection of the first dropdown.
My fieldset:
 <fieldset name="filters_fieldset">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Filters</label>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <sortOrder>30</sortOrder>
    </settings>
    <dynamicRows name="filters">
        <settings>
            <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Record</addButtonLabel>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
        </settings>
        <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
          
            <!-- First Dropdown -->
            <field name="filter_name" formElement="select">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filter_name</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Filter Name</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="My\Catalog\Model\Source\Category\AvailableFilters"/>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>

            <!-- Second Dropdown -->
            <field name="filter_value" formElement="select">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filter_value</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Filter Value</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>

                        <item name="switcherConfig" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="ajaxUrl" xsi:type="url" path="/admin/catalog/category/filterOptionsByName"/>
                            <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">filter_name</item>
                            <item name="method" xsi:type="string">GET</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="My\Catalog\Model\Source\Category\FilterOptionsByName"/>
                            <filterBy>
                                <targetField>${ $.parentName }.filter_name</targetField>
                            </filterBy>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>
        </container>
    </dynamicRows>
</fieldset>

However, changing the Filter Name doesn't seem to invoke my ajax request, so the options are not getting populated for the second drop down. What can I do to accomplish this?

To create dependent dropdowns in a Magento 2 dynamic rows component, we need to ensure that the second dropdown is updated based on the selection of the first dropdown. The configuration you provided is mostly correct, but we need to ensure that the necessary JavaScript functionality is properly implemented to handle the dependency and AJAX request.
Here's a step-by-step guide to achieving this:
Step 1: Adjust the First Dropdown Configuration
Ensure that the first dropdown has the proper configuration to trigger the second dropdown when its value changes. You might also need to add a data-bind attribute that listens for changes.
Step 2: Modify the Second Dropdown Configuration
You need to set the second dropdown to listen for changes in the first dropdown. The filterBy configuration you've added seems to be correctly pointing to the first dropdown. However, make sure that your AJAX configuration is properly set up to trigger when the value changes.
Example Code
Here’s an updated version of your fieldset configuration with some adjustments:
<fieldset name="filters_fieldset">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Filters</label>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <sortOrder>30</sortOrder>
    </settings>
    <dynamicRows name="filters">
        <settings>
            <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Record</addButtonLabel>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
        </settings>
        <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
          
            <!-- First Dropdown -->
            <field name="filter_name" formElement="select">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filter_name</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Filter Name</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="My\Catalog\Model\Source\Category\AvailableFilters"/>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>

            <!-- Second Dropdown -->
            <field name="filter_value" formElement="select">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filter_value</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Filter Value</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="switcherConfig" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="ajaxUrl" xsi:type="url" path="/admin/catalog/category/filterOptionsByName"/>
                            <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">filter_name</item>
                            <item name="method" xsi:type="string">GET</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="My\Catalog\Model\Source\Category\FilterOptionsByName"/>
                            <filterBy>
                                <targetField>${ $.parentName }.filter_name</targetField>
                            </filterBy>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>
        </container>
    </dynamicRows>
</fieldset>

Step 3: JavaScript for Handling Changes
You might also need to add custom JavaScript to handle the dropdown change and trigger the AJAX request. Create a new JavaScript file in your module (e.g., view/adminhtml/web/js/filters.js) and add the following code:
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/utils',
], function ($, Form, utils) {
    'use strict';

    return Form.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            // Bind the change event for the first dropdown
            this.observe('filter_name');
            this.on('filter_name', this.onFilterNameChange.bind(this));
        },

        onFilterNameChange: function (value) {
            // Find the corresponding filter_value dropdown
            var filterValueField = this.getField('filter_value');

            // Clear the current options in the second dropdown
            filterValueField.setOptions([]);

            // Make an AJAX request to populate the second dropdown based on the first dropdown's value
            if (value) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.getConfig('ajaxUrl'),
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { filter_name: value },
                    success: function (data) {
                        filterValueField.setOptions(data.options);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.error('Error fetching filter options.');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

Step 4: Update Your UI Component
Make sure to include your JavaScript file in your UI component XML:
<settings>
    <jsConfig>
        <component>Vendor_Module/js/filters</component>
    </jsConfig>
</settings>

Final Steps

Clear Cache: After making these changes, clear the cache and refresh the admin panel.
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush


Testing: Add dynamic rows and test the functionality of the dropdowns. When you change the first dropdown, the second dropdown should populate with the corresponding options based on the selection.


Conclusion
This approach ensures that your second dropdown is populated based on the selection of the first dropdown using AJAX in Magento 2. If you encounter any issues, please check your browser's console for errors, and ensure that your AJAX URL is returning the expected data format.

-1 for copy/pasting a ChatGPT answer (I used it extensively and it wasn't helpful for achieving the solution I wanted with no JS).
I wanted to do this without custom JS but I ended up having to resort to use it, as the default behavior of the dropdown was not invoking my controller to fetch new options for the dependent dropdown when the parent dropdown was changing.

@sschilli Hope, you're doing well, This thing I perform by myself I didn't copy anywhere personally before I had some kind of requirement, So I made it through the filters.js wrote in my extension, and managed the stuff, So for you, I prepared something like that, But your approach is different without js if we don't want to implement we can not make dependent if we want to make dependent things with js with the js we can finished out needs,
